# Can two different apps share NGXS store?

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular10

If I have two Angular apps running on separate ports, and app 1 adds something to the store, can app 2 retrieve it provided app 2 knows the exact name of the state getting added to the store?

If so, is there anything particular(outside of normal store setup) that app 2 needs to do to be able to access the store?

Comment: I would think not.  I am guessing since the store would be configured in a different app module, the second app wouldn't have access to it

Comment: you are going to need a backend for this

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by making both applications angular web components and then installing them inside a host app. App 1 and App 2 will now be interacting with App 3's store.